# LateInitializationError: Field '_instance@717240915' has not been initialized Error

Tags: flutter, dart, parse-server, back4app, custom-object

I m using [parse_server_sdk_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/parse_server_sdk_flutter) 3.0.0 to use parse server (back4app) in my app. I created custom class of ParseObject, when I m creating an instance of that custom object I m getting the above mentioned (In the title) error. I think it's because of null safety and I know that this version of package doesn't support null safety. Is there any other way to solve custom parse object creating or initializing ?

I m creating custom object as below !

```
class MyObject extends ParseObject implements ParseCloneable {

  MyObject() : super('MyObject'); //Getting error here !
  MyObject.clone(): this();

  @override clone(Map map) => MyObject.clone()..fromJson(map);
}
```

Registration part

```
await Parse().initialize(
        keyApplicationId,
        keyParseServerUrl,
        clientKey: keyParseClientKey,
        debug: true,
        liveQueryUrl: keyLiveQueryUrl,
        autoSendSessionId: true,
        registeredSubClassMap: <String, ParseObjectConstructor>{
     'MyObject': () => MyObject(),
   },
    );
```

Initialization Part

MyObject object = MyObject();

Comment: Have you registered the custom class either in the initialization or using the registerSubClass function? More details in here: https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Flutter/tree/master/packages/dart#custom-objects

Comment: I registered in the initialization part !

Comment: And also when using QueryBuilder on that custom object, it gives the same error ! Ex: QueryBuilder<MyObject> builder = QueryBuilder<MyObject>(MyObject());

Comment: Would you mind to share the code that you used to initialize and register?

Comment: Code Updated bro  !

Comment: So the error happens when you do `MyObject object = MyObject();` right? Could you please double check if this code is actually running after the initialization code?

Comment: Thank you so much bro ! This is the mistake ! I m using before it !

Comment: Hey bro ! One more question, I have a column in database a type of JSONArray which data looks like [{'name':'ABC','available':false},{'name':'MNO','available':true},other data...] and I want to query the values if values does not contains available:true ? How can I do this ?

Comment: Would you mind to open a new question and share what you've tried so far?